# Melting data to produce a plot using a 3D scatter plot for frequency

Tags: r

Using this example code from [here](https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/):

```
library(plotly)

data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv")

data_2007 <- data[which(data$year == 2007),]
data_2007 <- data_2007[order(data_2007$continent, data_2007$country),]
data_2007$size <- data_2007$pop
colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4', '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

p <- plot_ly(data_2007, x = ~gdpPercap, y = ~lifeExp, z = ~pop, color = ~continent, size = ~size, colors = colors,
             marker = list(symbol = 'circle', sizemode = 'diameter'), sizes = c(5, 150),
             text = ~paste('Country:', country, '<br>Life Expectancy:', lifeExp, '<br>GDP:', gdpPercap,
                           '<br>Pop.:', pop)) %>%
  layout(title = 'Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007',
         scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'GDP per capita (2000 dollars)',
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                      range = c(2.003297660701705, 5.191505530708712),
                      type = 'log',
                      zerolinewidth = 1,
                      ticklen = 5,
                      gridwidth = 2),
               yaxis = list(title = 'Life Expectancy (years)',
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                      range = c(36.12621671352166, 91.72921793264332),
                      zerolinewidth = 1,
                      ticklen = 5,
                      gridwith = 2),
               zaxis = list(title = 'Population',
                            gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                            type = 'log',
                            zerolinewidth = 1,
                            ticklen = 5,
                            gridwith = 2)),
         paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
         plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)')
```

Using this it is possible to produce a 3D scatter plot for 3 different dimensions.

I have the following dataset:

```
grid <- structure(list(stock = structure(1:6, .Label = c("stock1", "stock2", 
"stock3", "stock4", "stock5", "stock6"), class = "factor"), company = structure(1:6, .Label = c("company1", 
"company2", "company3", "company4", "company5", "company6"), class = "factor"), 
    predirctor = structure(1:6, .Label = c("predictor1", "predictor2", 
    "predictor3", "predictor4", "predictor5", "predictor6"), class = "factor"), 
    count = c(6L, 12L, 4L, 9L, 15L, 23L)), .Names = c("stock", 
"company", "predirctor", "count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I would like to use the previous 3D scatter plot in order to vizualize my data. The three dimensions are: stock, company and predirctor. And the count column is the number. Using the code:

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x = df$stock, y = df$company, z = df$predirctor,
        marker = list(color = df$count, colorscale = c('#FFE1A1', '#683531'), showscale = TRUE)) %>%
  add_markers() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Weight'),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'Gross horsepower'),
                     zaxis = list(title = '1/4 mile time')),
         annotations = list(
           x = 1.13,
           y = 1.05,
           text = 'Miles/(US) gallon',
           xref = 'paper',
           yref = 'paper',
           showarrow = FALSE
         ))
```

I take only the lines of plot. I can understand why this is happening because the data that needed for this plot must be different numbers from the three dimensions. Having only count column it is like I have one dimension. Using this plot I would like when someone see this can see example stock1-company1-predirctor1 has count 6. So instead of numbers in every line have this labels.
Is there any way to melt this data in order to produce the graph?